# How to maintain TempData when calling a RedirectToAction to another controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In a MVC 5 project, I have the following method in my controller;

```
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    TempData["User"] = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (user.IsValid(user.Email, user.Password, Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            string userData = user.Email;
            HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, userData);
            authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ManageAccount");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["User"] = user;
            TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        user.Message = "Invalid email/password";
        TempData["User"] = user; 
        TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Rather than having to keep repeating the code below to maintain the TempData, (as I will need to maintain TempData["CmsContent"] in my other controller Actions as well) like

```
TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
```

How can I call a Controller action, on another controller, whilst maintaining this TempData

Comment: You can't. If you redirect to another action, then that's another request, and it will use up the `TempData` store unless you persist those values again for the next request. If you need something more persistent than `TempData` that's what `Session` is for.

Comment: What happens to the TempData if the Session times out ?  Will it still be available if the next request is made ?

Comment: TempData *is* Session. It's just Session variables that are set to expire on the next request. If the session times out, everything in TempData goes with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments Session is an answer for the particular question, but there might be reasons that you want to avoid it. I've used [Brock Allen's solution](https://github.com/brockallen/CookieTempData) in the situation where you'd like the convienence of TempData but don't want to make use of server sessions.